# How to get precision for class 0 in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

Is there a way to get precision for class 0 in a binary classification model using `tf.keras.metrics.Precision`?

I tried setting `class_id` to 0, but it still gives the precision to class 1.

I would like to save the model with the best class 0 precision value using a callback, this is a reason I need a metric for the precision in compile.

I use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to create my dataset, the code looks the same for train/validation/test set (of course the train and val sets are shuffled):

```
ds_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        directory = test_path,
        batch_size = my_batch_size,
        image_size = (img_height, img_width),
        shuffle = False
    )
```

The precision metric is added in the compile method:

```
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(...),
              metrics = ["accuracy",
                         tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id = 0, name = "precision_0")
                        ]
              )
```

When evaluating the model with tensorflow `model.evaluate` I get the precision of class 1 instead of class 0:

```
   precision_0: 0.9556
```

Using `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` I got the precision for both classes:

```
           precision
       0     0.9723
       1     0.9556
```

I would like to get precision for class 0 in tensorflow too, in this case *0.9723*. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess an option is to use `sklearn.metrics.precision_score` with the parameter `pos_label=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom metric for this. If you are using `sigmoid` activation, then as a prediction result you get the *probability* of being class 1.

Once you subclass `tf.keras.metrics.Metric` you can alter this:

```
class my_precision_class_0(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, threshold, name='my_precision_class_0', **kwargs):
        super(my_precision_class_0, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')
        self.false_positives = self.add_weight(name='fp', initializer='zeros')
        self.threshold = threshold
        
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true_cls = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true[:, 0], 0), tf.int64)
        y_pred_cls = tf.cast(tf.less_equal(y_pred[:, 0], self.threshold), tf.int64)
        true_positives = tf.math.count_nonzero(y_true_cls * y_pred_cls)
        false_positives = tf.math.count_nonzero(y_pred_cls * (1 - y_true_cls))

        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.cast(true_positives, tf.float32))
        self.false_positives.assign_add(tf.cast(false_positives, tf.float32))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives / (self.true_positives + self.false_positives)

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0)
        self.false_positives.assign(0)
```

Here's what happens in `y_pred_cls` when using `tf.less_equal`, same thing applies for also `y_true_cls`:

```
x = tf.constant([0.4, 4.0, 6.0])
y = tf.constant([0.5])
r = tf.math.less_equal(x, y) # --> [True, False, False]
tf.cast(r, tf.int64) # --> [1, 0, 0]
```

We can use this metric in compile:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy', my_precision_class_0(threshold = 0.5),                                                
                       tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=16)
model.evaluate(X, y, batch_size = 1)
# --> loss: 0.3370 - accuracy: 0.8790 - my_precision_class_0: 0.8983 - precision: 0.8617

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_hat = (model.predict(X) > 0.5).astype(int)
print(classification_report(y, y_hat, digits=4))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support
           0     0.8983    0.8531    0.8751       497
           1     0.8617    0.9046    0.8826       503
    accuracy                         0.8790      1000
   macro avg     0.8800    0.8788    0.8789      1000
weighted avg     0.8799    0.8790    0.8789      1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to add the threshold as a parameter in the metric?

Comment: Sure, check the edited answer. Completely replaced the custom metric with the threshold version.

Comment: Although its solved. Is this really the best answer? I feel like this should be a simple input parameter solution scenario.

Comment: If you are using sigmoid with one neuron, this is the way to write it as a Keras metric. Otherwise you need to use softmax with categorical CE and specify class_id in tf.keras.metrics.Precision().

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround which can simply solve my case:

I use `class_names` parameter of `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to define the order of the classes, adding my "class 0" as second class:

"class_names: Only valid if "labels" is "inferred". This is the explicit list of class names (must match names of subdirectories). Used to control the order of the classes (otherwise alphanumerical order is used)."

The modified code to create the dataset:

```
ds_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = test_path,
    class_names = ["my_class_1", "my_class_0"]
    batch_size = my_batch_size,
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    shuffle = False
)
```

Not as elegant as defining a custom metric, but it works.
Important note: This only works with binary classification!