# Error when using custom precision metric in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(90, input_dim=900, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(90, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

m = keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=1)
# example data of suitable dimension, to offer MRE to SO
X_train = np.eye(900)
Y_train = np.ones((900, 1))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[m])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=1000)
```

When I use
`model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['Precision'])`

it works, but when I use Precision(class_id=1) (regardless of whether I substitute it as a variable), I get

```
ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 1 out of bounds. 
for '{{node strided_slice_1}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=1, end_mask=0, 
new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=2](Cast_1, strided_slice_1/stack, strided_slice_1/stack_1, strided_slice_1/stack_2)' 
with input shapes: [?,1], [2], [2], [2] and with computed 
input tensors: input[1] = <0 1>, input[2] = <0 2>, input[3] = <1 1>.
```

I don't know what any of this stuff means. Slice of WHAT is out of bounds? (I defined X_train and Y_train, of course, and they work when I just write metric=['Precision']).
FYI I'm doing this in SageMaker, if it makes any difference. There is no other code, so if I am failing to define some config thing, I don't know about that.

Comment: Did you forget to add code for `Precision()`?

Comment: Could you clarify? I created the object m from the class Precision. Is there something other than that that I need to do?

Comment: How is class `Precision` implemented

Comment: Well isnt `Precision` just a metric that the neural net will return when training and evaluating?

Comment: @FinnE yes, it is a metric for the neural net. However I don't understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: @ClaudiaR by passing it to model.compile?

Comment: I am a newbie to keras/ML so I need people to be really explicit. These questions seem odd to me and I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError using tensorflow.metrics.Recall(class\_id=1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469466/valueerror-using-tensorflow-metrics-recallclass-id-1)...You cannot set `class_id` to 1 on binary classification. Check also the source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/metrics/metrics.py#L868

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (im not confident), your data doesn't seem to be long enough? Like i think its having an issue trying to slice your data because it cant find an index 1 in the first dimension, meaning there is 1 or 0 items of data.

Try checking your data and see if what you expect is there.

Comment: OK, I think we're getting somewhere-- my data is long enough but it wasn't reindexed and thus didn't have an index 1. I thought it was saying it didn't have a dimension 1 (as in, indexing the dimensions, it failed to get a first dimension). Now I'm getting (perhaps unrelated?) ```InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.```

Comment: Im sorry I dont have a clue what that means. Again I would have to guess your data, because sometimes these modules dont catch everything that could be wrong with the data and then you get a seemingly unrelated error. I would once again verify that everything is how it should be.

Comment: I also see that you dont give a shape for your data (like `Dense(90, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,))` for example). I have only ever specified an input shape, and I dont have too much experience with keras, so I am not sure if that is normal. Could it be causing the error?

Comment: Reduced the size and now I'm getting the same out of bounds error again when my indexes are actually good-- ugh.

Comment: idea noted @ input shape (I don't know what I'm doing either haha). Thank you!

Comment: @Ejaz is the out of bounds error on dimension 1? What do you mean by reduced the size?