# tf recall precision not working for class_id 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision-recall

So, I am quite puzzled. I have the following arrays:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
y_true = np.array(
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y_pred = np.array(
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

You can see how the prediction got NO class label. Therefore, it should have a Recall of 0 (for class 0). So I compute it like this:

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=0)
m.update_state(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
m.result().numpy()
```

And it returns `1.0`! As if it is still giving me the Recall for class 1. So my question is, how can I get the right value? This question is also valid for Precision. However, precision also gives 1 which is no the case even for class 1.

For reference, the expected results are:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score

recall_score(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, pos_label=0)
precision_score(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, pos_label=0)
```

Comment: Class id does not work in a binary classification case.

Comment: I would ask how to do it then but I guess that will be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70348510/5931672) question

Comment: This one would also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469466/valueerror-using-tensorflow-metrics-recallclass-id-1/70471303#70471303